# Display a Captured Image on CardView

Tags: android, image, android-recyclerview, cardview

I am making an application using CardView / RecyclerView
I made the UI looks like I want to and with hardcoded data it works really well.

Here is an image of my CardView

[image]

So.What I want to do is :

Capture a picture
   Display that picture in my Card View

I have followed [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991319/capture-image-from-camera-and-display-in-activity#5991757) for capturing and displaying an Image and works great alone.

I'm not showing my code since I'm only asking for guidance and not for plain code.

My Java files are MainActivity, Item, ItemsAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

You can get Uri instead of bitmap from intent (use library like Picasso or Glide to load an image into `ImageView`). Then pass on an Uri to your model and refresh changed item.